# ASP.NET Identity MVC 5 how can I make the manage account view public so other users can see each other's profiles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.NET MVC5 application I have modified the Manage view so you can see your account details (name, email etc). Right now you can see your own profile if you are logged in. I have another page where users can store comments. What I want to implement is actually having the usernames show next to the comments and they should take you to that user's profile when you click on them. How exactly do I go about this? Should I store the UserID in each comment posted?

Comment: that are a couple of questions - to show a profile you probably have to add a view for it (or reuse the one you got in another action that takes a user-id as input instead of taking it from the request) - and **yes** of course you want to save the user-id to the comment (if you don't you'll have a *troll-fest* ;))

Comment: Okay I think I will have a different view then. Meaning the "my profile" page will be only for the user that is logged in to see where he or she can edit their data (change password and whatever) and when you click on his or hers username you will be taken to another view that takes that respective user you clicked (based on their UserId) as a parameter and retrieves their relevant data as text (no option of editing or whatever). I think this would be the optimal solution, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a public profile but you will need to have this Manage page in order to users change their profile. Make a copy of the Manage system and make the new one public for anyone.